# Node.js API / server post request

Tags: node.js, api, post, server

I started Node.js and general web few times ago and now I have a project where I have to develop a web server with an API in nodejs running on Express and I want to do it properly but I'm not sure if there's a the good way to do it.

It concerns about every post requests I'm sending to my API, here's an example :

*Sign up :*

I have a route `app.get('/signup')` and I'm sending a post request to my API to create new user. So with my guess I send a form with `action = /signup` `method = "post"` which means that on my server I've app.post('/signup'). In this post, I create a post request with all the information in my form and I send it to my API which creates the user and send back to the `app.post('/signup')` the answer. So basically, here the schema:

```
Get('/signup') -> Post('/signup') -> API('createUser') -> Post('signup')
```

Then I would like to go back to my app.get('/signup'), because I don't want to send html form the post one, and say "Hey it's ok" instead of showing the form so i'm doing a redirect but how could I know what to display in `Get('/signup')` ? Can I send a variable to know what to show to the user ? And btw, is it the proper way to do it ?

Thanks !

PS : it doesn't look very clear so here the code :

```
app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    if (req.session.userId) { res.end("Connected as " + req.session.name); }
    else {                 
        res.end('<html><p>As a guest, you\'re signing up : </p><form action="/signup" method="post">' +
                'First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>' +
                'Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>' +
                'email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>' +
                'password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>' +
                'role: <input type="text" name="role"><br>' +
                '<input type="submit" value="Submit">' +
                '</form></html>');
    }
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:4242/signup',
        form : {
            firstname : req.body.firstname,
            lastname : req.body.lastname,
            email : req.body.email,
            role : req.body.role,
            password : req.body.password
        }},
                 function (error, response, body) {
                     res.redirect('/signup');
                 });
});
```

Is it the good way to do it ?
Is there another way to send variable from post to get except the session variable ? (with the redirect) ?

Comment: I just can't understand your question. Please make it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but this is how I handle form submits with node.js.

Submit the form using jQuery/Ajax, so we can then get a response from the server after the POST.

```
$('#your-form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/signup',
        data: formData
    }).success(function(response) {

        if (response.success == '1') {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something - e.g. display an error message
        }

    });

});
```

Then on your Node.js server, you can handle the app.post('/signup') request, and once you're finished with your API calls, return a status message:

```
res.json({message: 'User created successfully.', success: '1'});
```

You can then use this JSON response to take the appropriate action.

Comment: We use almost this exact method here too, it's great for handling the server response.

Comment: I update my post to show you what i did, i would like to know if it's the good way to handle to response of the API.

Comment: What are you trying to send with the redirect? You could add it as a parameter value: `res.redirect('/signup?variable=string');` and then access the variable in your `app.get('/signup')` function by using `req.query.variable`.

Comment: Is it a proper way to do it ?

Comment: It depends on the data you're sending. If it's sensitive then don't use the query method. If it is sensitive, stick to use req.session variables.

Comment: Bascially, let assume than the signup failed, then the API send an error message to the server (POST), how can i send the error message from the post to the get by redirect ? Send all the sentence by parameter value doesn't look great x) I could directly res.end() from the post but i'm not sure it's really nice to return HTML with a post :/

Comment: That's why I would use ajax as in my original answer. Then everything is handled behind the scenes, and the page doesn't need to refresh or be redirect either.